# How do I breed a Silver Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I received a game alert that the "Silver Dragon" is an Epic dragon and can now be bred. What breeding combination is the best for this dragon, and what is its breeding time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The breeding pair for the Silver Dragon is not obvious since it is a Treasure Dragon, but the requirement is that the breeding pair include Cold and Metal elements.  If you're interested in the fastest breeding pairs that are commonly available for [I recommend](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/dragonvale-breeding-guide-epics):

> **Fastest Breeding Pair:** Chrome + Lichen    OR    Mine + Willow